# How long does a expect/tcl script execute

Tags: tcl, expect

I have written a telnet script to remote control a cisco switch, and it takes me about 2-3 minitus to get start, even though i write a short script with a single proc, it also take 2-3 minutes to start. The proc is as below.

```
    proc test_proc {} {
        puts "123"
    }
    test_proc
```

Is anybody who has faced this noisy problem?
Looking forward your helps...

Comment: The command which i used to run the script is as below.<br>#! /opt/ats5.2.0/bin/expect -f

Answer (score 1):

### Timing Scripts

To work out how long some piece of Tcl code takes to execute, use the `time` command. It's first argument is a script to measure. (It also takes an optional second argument that is the number of iterations to use; it defaults to 1, but higher numbers of iterations can be useful for measuring fast-running things.)

```
proc test_proc {} {
    puts "123"
}
puts [time {
    test_proc
}]
# I got "48 microseconds per iteration" when I tried it; YMMV...
```

Note that there is little point in measuring a procedure definition (unless you're very interested in the behavior of `proc` itself, but that's rather nerdy).

There's also a Unix system command called `time`, which works similarly (in a conceptual way) but rather measures the time for a program to run. Its output can vary quite a lot between systems; it's really intended to be human-readable after all.

### Optimizing Interpreter Startup Time

Much more concerning is how long a trivial script is taking to start; 2–3 minutes is an absolute *age* in computing terms. Is the machine where you are running this short of memory? (Heavy paging can slow programs down a lot.) Or perhaps you have all the libraries installed in an odd location (Tcl's package loading is particularly sensitive to problems when its libraries are installed in `/usr/lib` due to the size of that directory structure).  There were also some versions of Tcl (though *no current ones*) that had critical bugs in filename parsing and caching which tended to cause huge performance hits at startup time; what exact version of Tcl (and Expect too) are you using? Get the exact Tcl version with the `info patchlevel` command (`tcl version` only has enough precision from Tcl 8.5 onwards).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but I stumbled upon while searching for an answer, so I thought I'd post this here for the next one stumbling upon it.

The proposed time function does work, but not for a complete script, only on a function.

I found a way to use clock time with milliseconds which I use to measure runtime (seconds would be to inaccurate)

```
set start [clock clicks -milliseconds]

# all your code

set end [clock clicks -milliseconds]
set runtime [expr {$end - $start}]
puts "Runtime ${runtime}ms"
```